# Php: multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following checkbox created by a loop:

```
<input type='checkbox' value=0 name='<?php echo $question_id; ?>' />
```

Each checkbox will have a different ID, and when the user checks several checkboxes, I would like to gather all the id's and insert it into a table that relates an 'event' table with a 'questions' table.

However I am not getting the ids...I know I am supposed to use an array, but is that in the name attribute or the values attribute? Also, how do I pass on the IDs...does that go into the values field?

Comment: You can use the implode function implode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML:

```
<input type='checkbox' value=1 name='checkboxname[<?php echo $question_id; ?>]' />
```

In PHP:

```
$set_checkboxes = array_keys($_POST['checkboxname']);
```

Or, alternatively:

In HTML:

```
<input type='checkbox' value="<?php echo $question_id; ?>" name='checkboxname[]' />
```

In PHP:

```
$set_checkboxes = $_POST['checkboxname'];
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need something like ..

```
<input type='checkbox' value=<SOME UNIQUE VALUE> name='field_name[]' />
```

You'll loop through the `field_name` which happens to be an array.

Comment: That's great...does the value='have to be in quotes' or only if it's a string? I am passing a number/id...

Comment: I use quotes (sorry i missed it).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your input to this.

```
<input type='checkbox' value='<?php echo $question_id; ?>' name='questions[]' />
```

Now when you get the post with php it will return an array with all the question ids

```
$questionIds = $_POST['questions'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="checkbox" id="things[]" value="red"> Cat<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="things[]" value="blue"> Mouse<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="things[]" value="green"> Car<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="things[]" value="yellow"> DaniWeb
</form>
```

Your PHP:

```
<?php
$things = serialize($_POST['things']);

$query = "INSERT INTO table(things) values($things)";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```