# PHP loop through array of HTML textboxes

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I have an HTML form with a dynamic number of checkbox fields, all of which are encapsulated within a submit form.  When the form is submitted, I want to loop through the values of each checkbox field with a PHP script. At the same time, I have to keep a certain ID associated with the checkbox field so that when I loop through each one in my script, I can use the ID to update the correct row in my database.  Currently, I have:

```
<input checked="checked" name="attended_<?php echo($pid); ?>"
```

I'm just not sure how to go ahead and access all of the attended[] values from my PHP script (and keep the ID at the same time).  Would I use a multidimensional array like the following?

```
<input checked="checked" name="attended[<?php echo($i); ?>][<?php echo($pid); ?>]; ?>"
```

I'd appreciate any help on this.  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php: multiple checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751595/php-multiple-checkboxes), essentially, use `attended[<?php echo $pid;?>]` as a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when I create checkboxes I put an index in the name. This way you can loop through each checkbox in your submittion code.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbGroup[1]" value="y" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cbGroup[2]" value="y" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cbGroup[3]" value="y" />
```

and in your PHP

```
foreach($_POST['cbGroup'] as $index=>$checkbox) {}
```

You'll want to make sure your $_POST['cbGroup'] is set though because it won't be if the checkbox isn't checked.

Edit: Sorry, I should learn to read the question fully heh :) I use multidimensional arrays in PHP with HTML inputs all the time and I think it's the way I would go.

Comment: I did wind up using the multidimensional arrays to get it working. The tricky part, however, was submitting checkboxes that are NOT checked. For that, I had to add a hidden checkbox field in my HTML containing a value of "unchecked". This way, I can check for "unchecked" or "checked" in my PHP code. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I find it tricky as well. Usually my checkboxes are flags for yes or no so when I sanitize my code I'll always do $_POST['mycheckbox'] = isset($_POST['mycheckbox']) ? 'y' : 'n'; to avoid having empty indexes :) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

lets say this is data from form

```
<input checked="checked" name="attended[1]; ?>"
<input checked="checked" name="attended[2]; ?>"

<input checked="checked" name="attended[3]; ?>"
<input checked="checked" name="attended[4]; ?>"

<input checked="checked" name="hello[1]; ?>"
<input checked="checked" name="hello[2]; ?>"
```

this is how it would look as array. not needed its just for show

```
// $k        =>      $v
$attended[1]='blah blah';
$attended[2]='blah blah';
$attended[3]='blah blah';
$attended[4]='blah blah';

$hello[1]='blah blah';
$hello[2]='blah blah';
```

science bit

```
foreach($attended as $k=>$v){

$sql = "UPDATE mytable SET attended = '$v', hello = '{$hello[$k]}' where id = '$k'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Cannot query the database.<br />" . mysql_error());

}
```

all associated data should have same pid e.g

```
<input checked="checked" name="attended[1]; ?>"
<input checked="checked" name="hello[1]; ?>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do it with a hidden field which is sort of 'associated' with the checkbox by the name:

```
<input checked="checked" name="attended_<?php echo($i); ?>"
<input type="hidden" name="attended_<?php echo($i); ?>_reference" value="<?php echo($pid); ?>" />
```

So while processing the POST-data after a submit, you could put the references together again with some string-manipulation.