# Using jQuery serialize to put ajax values into a database select query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$allform = $_POST['allform'];
parse_str($allform, $output);

$allquery = "SELECT * FROM wp_users";
$names    = array();
$allresult = mysql_query($allquery) or die(mysql_error()); ?>

...

<?php

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($allresult)) {

    $names[] = $rows['user_email'];

}
?>
```

The allform variable is a jQuery serialize string:

```
var allform = $('form#all').serialize();
```

Basically, I want to put the values from the form in the front end into a mysql select query in the back end.

The form is a bunch of checkboxes so the idea is that the SELECT *something* will have different number of values depending on what the user checks. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: do the checkboxes all have the same name?

Comment: @Colin Not an INSERT, a SELECT because ill loop through the results and add them to a json_encode and display the results on the client-side. I just not sure how to go about getting the checkbox values in the select query.

Comment: @ZackMacomber, They have different names at the moment because I thought ild be able to distinguish them that way...

Comment: Setting your checkboxes to the same name will allow you to loop easily through them in the backend

Comment: Actually...just came across some posts on looping through checkboxes in PHP - have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930627/php-loop-through-array-of-html-textboxes?

Comment: Yeah im looking at it now. Only concern is that it repeats the query multiple times, but I guess this isnt too much of a bad thing?

Comment: You'll have to repeat the query for each unique value in the checkboxes anyway so that shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: @ZackMacomber i think you could leverage the fact that you can post checkboxes with the same name as an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do could be something like this. Your checkboxes should be like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="cream" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="choco" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="lime" />
```

server side you receive an array

```
$flavours = $_POST["checkboxes"];
$sql = "SELECT ".implode(',', $flavours)." FROM FLAVOURTABLE";
```